# How to customize ant design pro top navigation

Tags: antd, ant-design-pro

I want to customize the top navigation bar. I was only able to change the title from config.js.
I want to resize the logo, increase the height of nav, put space between menus and title. Can someone point me to the file I need to modify?

[image: Here is how it looks right now.] I can't show the real logo and full title. But, I think you will get the idea.

Comment: You need to use inline css on every element, for example for logo <img height={customizedSize} /> and ....

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `.less` file on inline css. Or even css. What I do is change in `global.less` for global change in antd classes. For component use a less file, like this, `<Table className={styles.table}/>`